# If a given condition is true, then do something. If it is false, then try again

Tags: java, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I am writing a script for a game and I want my character to walk a set amount of tiles but I can't quite get it to work. So I want to look for the tiles, if not, I don't want the array to go on, but return and try again.

```
public void printTile() {

    // Set length of the tile array. (i.e. how much tiles you need to interact with).
    Tile[] tileArray = new Tile[11];

    // Enter desired tiles in here, last digit is the plan which is standard 0.
    tileArray[0] = new Tile(2683, 3275, 0); 
    tileArray[1] = new Tile(2670, 3277, 0);
    tileArray[2] = new Tile(2657, 3276, 0);
    tileArray[3] = new Tile(2645, 3283, 0);
    tileArray[4] = new Tile(2635, 3289, 0);
    tileArray[5] = new Tile(2625, 3296, 0);
    tileArray[6] = new Tile(2617, 3297, 0);
    tileArray[7] = new Tile(2608, 3296, 0);
    tileArray[8] = new Tile(2598, 3297, 0);
    tileArray[9] = new Tile(2587, 3296, 0);
    tileArray[10] = new Tile(2577, 3298, 0);

    // Declare i, so we can count up the amount of tiles in this array.
    int i;

    // Self-explatanory. Array starts at 0. If i < amount of tiles in our array execute. Count up i every time, else it repeats the first tile.
    for(i = 0; i < tileArray.length; i++) {
        log("Walking to: " + tileArray[i]); 
        Time.sleep(1000); // Sleep is good for brain.

        if(Walking.canReach(tileArray[i])) {
            if(!Players.getLocal().isMoving() || Walking.getRealDistanceTo(tileArray[i]) < 2) {
                if(Walking.walkTileMM(tileArray[i])) {
                    Time.sleep(1000, 1500);

                    while(Walking.getDestinationDistance() > 1) {
                        Time.sleep(500);
                    }
                } else {
                    Time.sleep(700);
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Time.sleep(500);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use `continue` instead of `return` in your `else` clause. `continue` will skip to the next iteration of your loop instead of exiting the method.

Comment: Or even better, a `do-while` statement.

Comment: Thanks. But I want it try to click on the same array again that it couldn't click before. Continue moves on the next.

Comment: @user3923111 In that case, you can do `i--;continue;`, which will cause the same `tileArray` to be processed, but be careful, since you might get an infinite loop. Alternately, you can remove the `i++` from the for loop, and only increment it when some condition is met.

Comment: That's kinda what I was looking for, thanks! Jee, it's really so simple huh haha.